# Does modernizr distinguish between image and file system access?

Tags: modernizr, input-type-file

I'm using [Modernizr 3.0](http://v3.modernizr.com/download/) to check for input[type='file'] so I don't show an upload button to users who can't use it. I'm worried that `Modernizr.fileinput` will return false for users who don't have file system access but do have camera access via

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

I've tried checking this on browserstack but I'm still uncertain because I don't know how the various cameras respond on their VMs.

Does Modernizr distinguish between no file system access and no camera access or will `Modernizr.fileinput` return false if the user doesn't have file system access but does have camera access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Modernizr.filesystem` in conjunction with `Modernizr.fileinput` to see if the user has file system access.

Most desktop browsers support [filesystem API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem), but mobile browsers don't. A weaker check would be `Modernizr.filereader` but it'll work on most mobile browsers (barring older ones such as IE9 and old Androids).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't actually checked it though. For me  just using Modernizr.fileinput seemed to get the job done without breaking anything. At least it all worked fine and no one has complained yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the detect [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/924c7611c170ef2dc502582e5079507aff61e388/feature-detects/forms/fileinput.js).

It doesn't distinguish against anything, other than a few blacklisted user agents (which modernizr *does* use, if there is no sane alternative).